# How to append a script using javascript inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append a script generated in javascript inside a div created before in HTML, the problem is that only works if

```
$("<script />", {
        "src":"http://en.parkopedia.co.uk/js/embeds/mapView.js",
        "data-location":"http://en.parkopedia.co.uk/parking/" + search_field2,
        "data-options":"l=0&tc=0&zc=1&country=UK&ts[]=4&ts[]=3&ts[]=2",
        "data-size":"650:400",
        "id":"script_map",
        "type":"text/javascript"
    }).appendTo("body")
```

but if I change that for "$('#divId')" does not work, so the questions are:

1. How can I append that script generated inside a div when you click into a button?
2. How can I prevent to duplicate the script when I click twice in the button? Because it's working inside the body, but when I click again it shows two script windows. So i should remove the script before create a new one or if I get to put inside the div, clean all the childs inside.

I've created a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dperezq/oosttuc0/):

Update:
The main aim is to update the data-location when you click on the button and send the text inside the box to the data location to search there and show the script map below the textbox. Maybe it is another simple way to do it.

Comment: Why do you need the script to be inside a div? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Why do you think you need to append a script "inside a div"?

Comment: You want to append code as string ? or you want evaluate your code inside your website ?

Comment: scripts belong in the `<head>`, not in the `<body>`. and if you only want it to happen once, then set a flag variable and check for it next time. e.g. `if (!script_set) { ...insert script ... ; script_set = true; }`

Comment: The script is a map windows and I want to show it below the search box. Does not matter to be inside a div or not, but I thought it was easier to remove when you click again on the button. Because I have to remove the previous script before generate a new one. It's the only way that I know because I don't know how to reload the script  `data-location` when you click on the button

Comment: just tried changing to `<div id="map"`, it works fine ! http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/oosttuc0/1/

Comment: this is for your `2.` requirement (aviod duplicates) http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/oosttuc0/3/

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Thank you so much. The last solution is what I want to. But I don't know why it's working in jsfiddle but not in my project. I type just the same

Comment: @KishoreSahas do you know why the snippet does not work? Because I have the same problem when I do it in my website. Does not work when you click on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will answer your first question.

```
.appendTo("#map")
```

And for second question.

```
 if ($("#script_map").length > 0) {
            $("#map").html("");
        }
```

**DEMO :**

http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/oosttuc0/4/

**Code :**

```js
window.scripting = function () {
    if ($("#script_map").length > 0) {
     $("#map").html("");
    }
        var src_fld = document.getElementById('txt_f').value;

        $("<script />", {
            "src": "//en.parkopedia.co.uk/js/embeds/mapView.js",
                "data-location": "//en.parkopedia.co.uk/parking/" + src_fld,
                "data-options": "l=0&tc=0&zc=1&country=UK&ts[]=4&ts[]=3&ts[]=2",
                "data-size": "650:400",
                "id": "script_map",
                "type": "text/javascript"
        }).appendTo("#map")
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-pane carpark" id="main_view">
    <input type="text" id="txt_f" name="txt_f">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn" value="Submit" onclick="scripting(); return false;">
    <div id="map" name="map"></div>
    <iframe style="border:none" width="100%" height="500px" id="iFrame2" name="iFrame2"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: That's that I wanted, but in jsfiddle work fine, however in my project doesn't work. I click on the button and doesn't show anything, it happens the same in the above `Run code snippet` but my goal is to make it work as your jsfiddle. Maybe it's some library problem or something. I don't know but thanks for helping

Comment: This is the example that does not work, and is exactly the same as yours: https://jsfiddle.net/dperezq/oosttuc0/6/

You can try with some location - i.e -> "London"

Comment: just went through your fiddle. issue there is the JS and CSS files were not loaded , reason is the resource URLs are in HTTP protocol but as the jsfiddle is HTTPS , page blocks them from loading.  try this ... http://jsfiddle.net/dperezq/oosttuc0/6/

Answer (score 0):

Run the Date input line

```
DateInput('creneau_2',true,'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

you could just try and do it all in jQuery rather than mixing javascript selectors.

```
$("#test").append("<script type='text/javascript'>DateInput('creneau_2',true,'DD-MON-YYYY');</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Look this:

```js
function scripting(){
 var src_fld = document.getElementById('txt_f').value ;
    
    $("#main_view").find("script[id='test']").remove();
    console.log("Size: " + $("#main_view").size());
  
 $("<script id='test'/>", {
     "src":"http://en.parkopedia.co.uk/js/embeds/mapView.js",
  "data-location":"http://en.parkopedia.co.uk/parking/" + src_fld,
  "data-options":"l=0&tc=0&zc=1&country=UK&ts[]=4&ts[]=3&ts[]=2",
  "data-size":"650:400",
  "id":"script_map",
  "type":"text/javascript"
 }).appendTo($("#main_view"))
    
    console.log($("#main_view").html())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane carpark" id="main_view">  
    <input type="text" id="txt_f" name="txt_f">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn" value="Submit" onclick="scripting(); return false;">
    <div id="map" name="map"></div>
    <iframe style="border:none" width="100%" height="500px" id="iFrame2" name="iFrame2"></iframe>
</div>
```